# Actualizar Datos en una BD solo me actualiza algunas variables

Tags: php, pdo

Hola tengo un problema algunos de mis datos no se actualizan en mi base de datos 
 probé Pasando todo a un `if(){}` pero solo el país y el genero se actualizan alguien tiene idea de como arreglar el error ?
agradecería que añadieran algún ejemplo

ademas lo que trato de hacer es que el usuario elija lo que quiere actualizar 
ya sea el nombre de usuario o la contraseña de esta forma el usuario no tenga que actualizar todo los datos por fuerza 
ademas intente de que el usuario solo pueda cambiar su ID(nombre ) solo una vez pero como no me actualiza los datos no puedo verificar si funciona

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8',"","");
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if(!isset($id))
{
 header('location:/');
}

$message = '';

if(isset($_POST['edit_profile']))
{
 $check_query = "
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username AND id != $id
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($check_query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':username'  =>  trim($_POST["username"])
  )
 );
 $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
 if($total_row > 0)
 {
  $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Username Already Exists</div>';
 }
 else
 {
  if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $data = array(
    ':username'   =>trim($_POST["username"])
  );
  $query = "
  UPDATE user SET usuario=:username,no_name_c='no' WHERE id = $id
  ";
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $data = array(

    ':password'  => hash('sha512', $_POST["password"])
  );
  $query = "
  UPDATE user SET pasword=:password WHERE id = $id
  ";
}
if (isset($_POST['bio'])){
   $data = array(

   ':bio'    => trim($_POST["bio"])
  );
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET bio=:bio WHERE id = $id
   ";
 }
 if (isset($_POST['male'])) {
   $data = array(

   ':male'    => "Hombre"
  );
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET sexo=:male WHERE id = $id
   ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['famele'])){
   $data = array(

   ':famele'    => "Mujer"
  );
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET sexo=:famele WHERE id = $id
   ";
 }
 if (isset($_POST['bday'])) {
   $data = array(

   ':bday'    => trim($_POST["bday"])
  );
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET cumple=:bday WHERE id = $id
   ";
 }
 if (isset($_POST['pais'])) {
   $data = array(

   ':pais'    => trim($_POST["pais"])
  );
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET pais=:pais WHERE id = $id
   ";
 }
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  //$statement->execute();
  if($statement->execute($data))
  {
   $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Profile Updated</div>';
  }
 }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="css/000webhost.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">Edit Profile</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <?php
       foreach($result as $row)
       {
        echo $message;
       ?>
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Nombre de Usuario(ID)</label>
         <?php 

         if($row['no_name_c']=="no"){
             echo '<input type="text" name="username" readonly id="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$" required class="form-control" value="'.$row["usuario"].'"/>';
             echo '<small>Solo puedes cambiar el nombre una sola vez!</small>';
         }else{
             echo '<input type="text" name="username" id="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$" required class="form-control" value="'.$row["usuario"].'" />';
             echo '<small>Solo puedes cambiar el nombre una sola vez!</small>';
         }

         ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Contraseña</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Biografia</label>
         <textarea name="bio" id="bio" class="form-control"><?php echo $row["bio"]; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pais">Pais (<span><?php echo $row["pais"]; ?></span>)</label>
          <select name="pais"  class="form-control">
            <?php
            if ($row["pais"]=="") {
              echo "
              <option>Chile</option>
              <option>Mexico</option>
              <option>Argentina</option>
              <option>Colombia</option>
              <option>Otro</option>
              ";
            }else {
              echo "
              <option value='".$row["pais"]."' disabled>".$row["pais"]." (Pais Actual)</option>
              <option>Chile</option>
              <option>Mexico</option>
              <option>Argentina</option>
              <option>Colombia</option>
              <option>Otro</option>
              ";
            }
             ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bday">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
          <div class='input-group'>
            <input type='date' name="bday" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['cumple'];?>"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gn">Genero</label><br>
          <?php if ($row['sexo'] == "Hombre") {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="male" value="Hombre" checked="checked"> Hombre<br>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="famele" value="Mujer"> Mujer';
          }elseif ($row['sexo'] == "Mujer") {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="male" value="Hombre"> Hombre<br>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="famele" value="Mujer" checked="checked"> Mujer';
          }elseif ($row['sexo'] =="") {
            echo '
            <input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="male" value="Hombre"> Hombre<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="gn" name="famele" value="Mujer"> Mujer';
          }
          ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" name="edit_profile" id="edit_profile" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>

       </form>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Max, ¿Ya te fijaste si la estructura de tu tabla en MySql está correcta?, es decir, si los campos si están con el tipo de dato que se deben insetar, los caracteres... int, text, varchar...?

Comment: @Candelo hum algunos si otros no en el caso del usuario la contraseña si existen los datos

Comment: No me queda claro el problema.. hay algun error o que es lo que pasa?

Comment: @gbianchi no me actualiza los datos en mi base de datos al enviar el formulario algunos datos si se actualizan pero los otros no

Comment: Hay un lio de codigo ahi. En que casos actualiza unos y otros no? si mandas dos datos solo va a actualizar uno, eso es lo que ves que pasa?

Comment: País genero y edad de actualiza al mismo tiempo y también independientemente pero la contraseña y nombre no